# Is there any reason why lVals = [1, 08, 2011] throws an exception?

Tags: python

I have discovered one thing that makes me crazy. If I specify the following list:

```
lVals = [1, 01, 2011]
```

then no errors will be displayed, and the same will happen if I use `02,03,04,05,06,07`, but in case I use `08` or `09` as the second item in the list, I get the following exception:

```
>>> a = [26, 08, 2011]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = [26, 08, 2011]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Also the same behavior appears when I put these numbers (`08`,`09`) at the any location within list (eg. `[08,10,2011]`), even if I try to assign `08` to a single `int` variable I get the same exception.

Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: This is such a commom mistake for me. I always spent a lot of time trying to figure this out when it happens.

Comment: In Python 3 this won't be a problem -- octal literals start with `0o`.

Comment: @agf: "won't be a problem" in that `01` through `07` are also invalid tokens...

Comment: Really? I thought leading zeros were just to be ignored? Or at least there was going to be a meaningful error message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`08` is attempting to parse `8` as an octal digit. It isn't one.

Comment: Thank you @Wooble. It so simply))). However seems that Python 2.7 console throwing not a very notable exception: 'invalid token' while IronPyton 2.6 throwing clearer exception: 'FatalError:bad char for the integer value: '8' (base 8):08'

Comment: @Artsiom: that looks like an IronPython change; Cpython 2.5, 2.6, and 3.2 all give the "invalid token" message. I suspect the conversion in IronPython is being done at a lower level within .Net.

Comment: maybe, anyway sometimes IronPython looks better, sometimes worse - but i like it more

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know Python, but I'd guess it takes the starting 0 as the beginning of an octal literal.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you're trying to do is split a date and put it in a list. This is what works for me:

```
>>> date = "28-08-2011".split("-")
>>> for i, num in enumerate(date):
...     date[i] = int(num, 10) # changes octal to decimal, thus losing the prefix 0
... 
>>> date
[28, 8, 2011]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the zero prefix would specify an Octal value - so 01...07 are fine, 08 would be an error as there is no 8 in Octal.