# Why does this dictionary definition raise a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason why lVals = [1, 08, 2011] throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064936/is-there-any-reason-why-lvals-1-08-2011-throws-an-exception)

I am defining a dictionary to map day numbers to their respective word. For some reason the following code raises a "SyntaxError: invalid token" and highlights "08"

```
days = {01:"first", 02:"second", 03:"third", 04:"fourth", 05:"fifth", 06:"sixth", 07:"seventh", 08:"eighth", 09:"nineth", 10:"tenth", 
    11:"eleventh", 12:"twelvth", 13:"thirteenth", 14:"fourteenth", 15:"fifteenth", 16:"sixteenth", 17:"seventeenth", 18:"eighteenth",
    19:"nineteenth", 20:"twentieth", 21:"twenty-first", 22:"twenty-second", 23:"twenty-third", 24:"twenty-fourth", 25:"twenty-fifth",
    26:"twenty-sixth", 27:"twenty-seventh", 28:"twenty-eighth", 29:"twenty-nineth", 30:"thirtieth", 31:"thirty-first"}
```

modifying the code so that 08 and 09 become 98 and 99 stops any errors, as in the code below:

```
days = {01:"first", 02:"second", 03:"third", 04:"fourth", 05:"fifth", 06:"sixth", 07:"seventh", 98:"eighth", 99:"nineth", 10:"tenth", 
    11:"eleventh", 12:"twelvth", 13:"thirteenth", 14:"fourteenth", 15:"fifteenth", 16:"sixteenth", 17:"seventeenth", 18:"eighteenth",
    19:"nineteenth", 20:"twentieth", 21:"twenty-first", 22:"twenty-second", 23:"twenty-third", 24:"twenty-fourth", 25:"twenty-fifth",
    26:"twenty-sixth", 27:"twenty-seventh", 28:"twenty-eighth", 29:"twenty-nineth", 30:"thirtieth", 31:"thirty-first"}
```

and the output becomes:

```
{1: 'first', 2: 'second', 3: 'third', 4: 'fourth', 5: 'fifth', 6: 'sixth', 7: 'seventh', 10: 'tenth', 11: 'eleventh', 12: 'twelvth', 13: 'thirteenth', 14: 'fourteenth', 15: 'fifteenth', 16: 'sixteenth', 17: 'seventeenth', 18: 'eighteenth', 19: 'nineteenth', 20: 'twentieth', 21: 'twenty-first', 22: 'twenty-second', 23: 'twenty-third', 24: 'twenty-fourth', 25: 'twenty-fifth', 26: 'twenty-sixth', 27: 'twenty-seventh', 28: 'twenty-eighth', 29: 'twenty-nineth', 30: 'thirtieth', 31: 'thirty-first', 98: 'eighth', 99: 'nineth'}
```

the previously erroneous keys have moved to the end of the dictionary.

Many thanks to the person who spots what is going on here,

James

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number `0` is a prefix on an integer literal indicating that it is an octal number in python.

...which as I accidentally omitted, and as @larsmans so kindly pointed out in his comment, limits the number to containing only the numerals `0` through `7`, excluding `8` and `9`.

Though, also of note, this is the syntax in Python 2.x - it was changed as of Python 3.0, ostensibly for the exact reason that you came here.  [PEP 3127](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax) contains the details of the change.

The most relevant bit:

> Almost all currently popular computer languages, including C/C++, Java, Perl, and JavaScript, treat a sequence of digits with a leading zero as an octal number. Proponents of treating these numbers as decimal instead have a very valid point -- [...] the entire non-computer world uses decimal numbers almost exclusively.

Comment: ... and obviously, `08` is not a valid octal number. +1.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, prefixing a number with a `0` denotes it as being octal. So `08` and `09` give errors because the digits `8` and `9` don't exist in octal. Just get rid of the leading `0` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

A number starting with 0 and containing only digits is interpreted in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). 8 and 9 are not valid octal numbers. If you replace 08 and 09 with 8 and 9, the code will work.